# Converting vst track to midi?

Tags: midi, vst, cubase

What I usually do when I do this is that I just copy paste from the vst track to the midi track which works in cubase, but is there a way to convert a vst track to a midi track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "VST" track just has MIDI data in it already (which is being sent to a VST), then you should be able to copy that MIDI data out just as you describe. If it isn't (say, it's got audio data that's just being processed by a VST) then there no universal way to do this, since MIDI is not audio.

Some tools do exist that will attempt to transcribe note data from audio recordings as MIDI, but I haven't had a lot of luck with them.